# How to cancel a postgres query in java/JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

How do I cancel a long running postgres query via JDBC or Java?

The usecase would be that an user starts a query on a postgres database 
via a front end, but then he decides otherwise and wants to 
abort/cancel the currently running query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `java.sql.PreparedStatement.cancel()` method. Check whether postgres JDBC driver supports this method. As far as I can see from the source code of the latest postgres JDBC driver it **does** stop the query.

Comment: Thanks Boris, thats it. Works like a charm.

Comment: If the cancel itself hangs you can do more aggressive things like closing the connection...GL! :)