# How to shut down all threads in executor service immidiately?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have used `shutDown()` and `shutDownNow()`, but both method does not stop all threads immediately. `shutDownNow()` is more preferable among these two but it waits for the running thread to complete it's task. In my scenario I have a huge task dealing with **postgres** database and I want to shut down that thread immediately without waiting for the completion of execution.

What is the way to shut down the all the threads immediately?

Comment: From the JavaDoc: `For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.`. Do your threads respond to such thing?

Comment: @npinti. If I change code to handle the interrupt it is very big change. I have so many for loop in my code. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you are executing a query, even if you interrupt the thread, query might not stop executing, so look at that as well.

Comment: Ideally threads always check some condition when executing so that they *know* when they need to stop. If you have a bunch of `for` loops which keep going until you are done, then, there is no way to stop your thread until all the processing is done, or else some unhandled exception takes place.

Comment: @Sandeep I can wait for one query to run. But It should stop after running that query. Here it continues to run multiple database and other operations.

Comment: There exists a method in Thread class to immediately stop threads. However, that one should not be used. Recommended to read [Thread.stop API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) which mentions that the executing thread actively needs to regularly check if it should stop. It could help to understand why stopping the thread immediately is not a good idea.

Comment: @Alderath I have also read about `stop()`, But I can cause deadlock situation. So as you say I can not use this in the code.

Comment: If your code (or the libraries it uses) are waiting on I/O (for instance network traffic) the interrupt will not be honored until the wait completes.

Answer (score 1):

shutdownNow : 
Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use awaitTermination to do that.

shutdown : 
Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29

or you can see this :

You can use an ExecutorService instead which combines a thread pool with a queue of tasks.

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
 // or
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

 // submit as many tasks as you want.
 // tasks must honour interrupts to be stopped externally.
 Future future = service.submit(new MyRunnable());

 // to cancel an individual task
 future.cancel(true);

 // when finished shutdown
 service.shutdown();
```

Comment: I am using executor service. I can not use `awaitTermination()` because it has the same issue I am facing right now. That is I have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

The single "clean" way to stop the threads is, if you have some loops inside, to stop the loop through some boolean variable like "stopThread", and you have to handle the variable.

Example:

public void run(){

for(int i=0; i<1000000 && (!stopThread) ; i++){

```
// do something
```

}
}

Comment: Any type of stop thread, wait the thread to stop, so is your bad luck, or you wait or you implement. :D

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possible in safe way.

The safe way to shutdown the executor service as per oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

If you really want to follow a crude way, I will suggest a solution which may not be 100% accurate and I don't recommend personally. I would like to use ExecutorService methods instead of this crude solution.

1. Create your own thread and thread pool as per this [article](http://oppansource.com/implementing-own-thread-pool-in-java/)
2. Add one more boolean in `Worker` thread - `boolean runNow = true;`
3. run method of Worker thread will be like this : `while ( runNow) { // your logic }`
4. When you want to shut down all the threads, add one more method in `ThreadPoolManager`. Iterate through  `myQueue` and interrupt all `Runnables`. Catch that interrupted exception and make the boolean `runNow` as false.

Comment: I can think about `awaitTermination()` but using this method I have to wait and I have not found any other method to stop all jobs without waiting and without deadlock. Second way is requires too much change in code.

Comment: In a safer way, you can't stop all threads immediately. You have to wait. I don't see any solution to your problem without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you call the database, you could try to explicitly cancel the query. Se [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526211/how-to-cancel-a-postgres-query-in-java-jdbc).

Comment: I am using hibernate.